# AddThis : Cutomization

Tags: addthis

I have added Addthis widget to a website. Here is the autogenerated code which I have tweaked little bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var addthis_config = {
        "data_track_clickback": true,
        services_compact: 'facebook, twitter,googlebuzz, digg,  stumbleupon',
        services_expanded: 'facebook, twitter,googlebuzz, digg,  stumbleupon',
        ui_cobrand: "ABC Company",
        ui_header_color: "#ffffff",
        ui_header_background: "#000000"


    }
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4dde778a54a20e05"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

           var addthis_share = {
               templates: { twitter: 'check out {{title}} : {{url}} @ABC' },
                url_transforms : { clean: true }

           }
</script>

<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                <a  class="addthis_button_compact">
                    <img alt="Share" src="../images/icons/share.gif" /><img alt="ABC" src="../images/icons/financial_tip.png" />
                </a>

        </div>
```

I have added facebook, twitter, google buzz, StumbleUpon and Digg links inside the ADdthis compact and expandable widgets.
When I click the Share link, following window pop ups:
[image]
I dont want the Addthis footer to appear in the pop up window. I tried finding the div with jquery doc load and removing it..but it didnt help.

Other thing is when I click FB, it opens my account and the following message is displayed about posting on my wall:
[image]
Addthis is appending some garbage at the end of the shared url:
e.g after index.aspx starting from # to ;facebook ..it is appending some data that is irrelevant... how to fix it ..any idea...
If I share it on twitter, the login screen to twitter
[image]
I dont want the Addthis message in footer..how to hide/delete it
Similar to FB, when i login to my twitter account, some garbage is added to the end of the shared url:
[image]

Moreover, whenever i click any icon inside the compact Addthis list, Fb or twitter, a small window pop ups:
[image]

Can anyone help me with these.

THanks.

Answer (score 3):

About twitter issue, you can use somthing like this..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

 var addthis_share = 
 { 
 templates: { twitter: '{{title}}: {{url}}' }
 }
 </script>
```

And change

```
 <a class='addthis_button_tweet' tw:via='YOUR-USER-NAME'/>
```

I never tried other services. But have a look at Addthis API. I think you can find out something.

Answer (score 3):

Malinda's answer is basically correct but doesn't explain what's going on - I think it's important to understand a bit more.

The question says, "Addthis is appending some garbage at the end of the shared url".  This isn't garbage.  The value after the #hashtag is a semi-random number generated by Addthis that can help you build really useful social media reports that can even show you which of your shares are re-shares - a critical component in modeling viral growth rates (which is what you want from social sharing).  You can read more about that here: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381254-address-bar-sharing-analytics.

What Malinda's solution does is override the default Addthis Twitter template to omit this tracking data.  That certainly works - you should just realize what you're giving up in terms of tracking your social media campaign.